# C# How to write down a parameter of a constructor of a class's method that you are using in a different class?

Tags: c#, class, parameters, xna

So I'm trying to use a bool method UpHealth from the class Level in the class Health. The constructor however of the Level class has the parameter levelIndex. I don't know what to write on the parameter spot after new Level in the class Health. This is the level class:

```
partial class Level : GameObjectList
{
protected bool upHealth;

public Level(int levelIndex)
{
    //Stuff
}

public bool UpHealth()
{
    upHealth = false;
    SpriteGameObject healthpack = this.Find("uphealth") as SpriteGameObject;
    Player player = this.Find("player") as Player;
    if (healthpack.CollidesWith(player))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This is the Health class:

```
class Health : GameObjectList
{
Level level;

public Health(int layer = 3, string id = "") : base(layer, id) 
{
    //Stuff
    level = new Level( <--WHAT DO I WRITE HERE?--> );
}

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    AnimatedGameObject rocket = GameWorld.Find("rocket") as AnimatedGameObject;

    foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
    {
        SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
        if (level.UpHealth())
        {
            this.Add(h);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably an easy fix but I can't figure out what to do.

Comment: A levelIndex as int value? An arbitrary number? Depends a bit on what you *want* to put there.

Comment: Think about the usage and meaning of `levelIndex` for `Level` constructor and pass an integer value that the `Level` class expect. Or maybe you can provide a default value for levelIndex, like you did for layer `layer=3`, then you don't need to pass any value to `Level` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> new Level( <--WHAT DO I WRITE HERE?--> )

Well, look at the constructor:

```
public Level(int levelIndex)
```

You write an `int` there.  Any integer value would satisfy the compiler and allow the code to execute.  Something as simple as:

```
new Level(0)
```

or an integer variable, such as:

```
new Level(layer)
```

As for what *conceptual* value you *should* use, that's really up to you.  We didn't design your application, so we can't really say how you should be initializing your objects.  But at a strictly technical level, if your constructor expects an integer then you would give it an integer.